# Deep Nested XML

Tags: xml, apache-flex, datagrid, nested, xmllist

I am trying to display a list of items in a datagrid from an XMLList.

```
<Series no="1">
    <file>
        <filenum>1</epnum>
        <prodnum>4V01</prodnum>
        <title>Series #1 - File #1</title>
    </file>
    <file>
        <filenum>2</epnum>
        <prodnum>4V02</prodnum>
        <title>Series #1 - File #2</title>
    </file>
</Series>
<Series no="2">
    <file>
        <filenum>1</epnum>
        <prodnum>4V01</prodnum>
        <title>Series #2 - File #1</title>
    </file>
    <file>
        <filenum>2</epnum>
        <prodnum>4V02</prodnum>
        <title>Series #2 - File #2</title>
    </file>
</Series>
```

My current code allows me to retrieve every Series into an XMLList and then i have a nesteddatagrid class that allows me to do things like.

```
<classes:NestedDataGrid width="100%" height="100%" id="gridFiles" dataProvider="{filesList}" >
<classes:columns>
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Season" dataField="@no" width="60"/>
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Episode" dataField="file.filenum" width="60"/>
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Title" dataField="file.title"/>
</classes:columns>
</classes:NestedDataGrid>
```

However this displays the datagrid with two rows, the first row has 1 in the Series column and then the two files crammed into the second cell in the same row. The second row is the same but has the number 2 in the Series column and the two series #2 files crammed into the cell next to it.

If i do not use the nested data class i can pull the files using Series.file instead and all 4 of the files list correctly, however i do not get the Series number for each...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current structure of the xml, it's easier to represent it with a two column grid - first column being the series number, and second column being another 2 or 3 column DataGrid that displays file details. But if you don't wanna change the structure, the following code is what you need. Note that since `dataField` property is not set, you have to specify a `sortCompareFunction` for sorting the grid based on series number - otherwise it might throw exceptions while trying to sort.

```
<classes:NestedDataGrid width="100%" height="100%" id="gridFiles" 
  dataProvider="{filesList.Series.file}" >
  <classes:columns><!-- classes copy pasted from OP's code. Whats that? -->
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Season" labelFunction="getSeries" width="60"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Episode" dataField="filenum" width="60"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Title" dataField="title"/>
  </classes:columns>
</classes:NestedDataGrid>
private function getSeries(item:Object, col:DataGridColumn):String
{
  return XML(item).parent().@no;
}
```

---

UPDATE:

```
<mx:DataGrid width="100%" height="100%" id="gridFiles" > 
  <mx:columns>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Season" labelFunction="getSeries" width="60"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Episode" dataField="epnum" width="60"/>
    <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Title" dataField="title"/>
  </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>

gridFiles.dataProvider = XML(event.result).descendants('episode');
//use the same getSeries function as above
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, how would you suggest separating the data grids? how would the Series grid know how many cells to fill with the first Series number? I do not really understand the code above, i know how it is supposed to work but i cannot get it to work. I have added the function as a public function into the mx:Script tag.

Comment: Your xml is not well formed. `<filenum>1</epnum>` is wrong, change it to `<filenum>1</filenum>`

Comment: change dataProvider from `filesList.series.file` to `filesList.Series.file` (uppercase Series)

Comment: And what is the `classes:` namespace? Doesn't `columns` belong to `mx`?

Comment: i have
    seriesList = XML(evt.result).descendants("Series");         
    Application.application.ManagePage.seriesList = seriesList;

in a class function.
forget about the classes: namespace i have removed that now. And also the XML is correct i just changed it to make it easier to understand but forgot the ending tag.

Comment: what does `trace(evt.result)` give?

Comment: http://pastebin.org/46365 - please remember i changed the names etc to make it easier so i do know the correct dataprovider names etc.

Comment: Series == Season and file = episode, right? Now what all do you need in your DataGrid?

Comment: that is correct, in the datagrid i need each episode listed with the season number from the upper nest and then the epnum, title, airdate, and i have a urlRenderer that makes a button for the link.

Comment: you make that look so simple lol, thank you so much!
Should i start a new topic or can i ask the next question here?